# Tkinter Entry not displaying data

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an entry widget that is being built and displaying.  However, the data in the widget is not displaying - so it shows as an empty entry box.
The variable being used to load the data - `apiObjectGlobal.description` is populated.  Thoughts why the value is not being displayed?

If I do a get on `self.descEntry` I get no data, so it would appear the definition of the Entry widget may not be populating as I expect.

```
self.description = StringVar()
self.ldesc = StringVar()
self.ldesc.set("Description")

self.ldesc = Label(self, textvariable=self.ldesc)
self.ldesc.grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = "E")

self.descEntry = Entry(self, width=30, textvariable = apiObjectGlobal.description)
self.descEntry.grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = "W")

self.descEntry.bind("<Return>", self.saveDescription)
```

Comment: your code is not complete. What is `apiObjectGlobal.description`? Is it a `StringVar`? Where is it set?

Comment: Why are you setting the `textvariable` attribute of `self.descEntry` to  `apiObjectGlobal.description`? Did you mean `...textvariable = self.description)`?

Answer (score 0):

I realized what I was doing wrong.  Basically I was setting textvariable to self.description (after making a change as noted) but to get the data to display I had to use the setter (.set()) and I was not doing that.  A small, but critical, mix-up.